# Lync SDK 2013 - Join Meeting throws 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

Tags: sdk, lync-2013

I am trying to run 'Join meeting sample' in Lync SDK 2013. Below code in the sample throws an exception "Value does not fall within the expected range.".

```
string conferenceUrl = MeetUrl.Text; // in the form of "conf:sip:wewa@microsoft.com;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:4FNRHN16";
IAsyncResult ar = Automation.BeginStartConversation(conferenceUrl, 0, StartConversation_Callback, null);
```

I am passing ConferenceUrl in the format "conf:sip:wewa@microsoft.com;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:4FNRHN16". It keeps throwing the same error. Am i missing something.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in the `SDK`. If you add an `"?"` at the end of the `conference uri`, your code will work.

```
conf:sip:rojimene@microsoft.com;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:HELLOWORLD?
```